# AttributeError with for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to define a function called all_extreme() that takes a tuple of strings and returns `True` if all of the strings contain exclamation points. If any of the strings are missing exclamation points, then it should return `False`. This function needs to use the function extreme() that I have already defined. So `all_extreme(("!","Bogus!","!YES!"))` and `all_extreme(("Nifty!","!!"))` should both return `True`, but all_extreme(("Cool!","Okay...")) and `all_extreme(("square","..."))` should both return `False`.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def extreme(x):
    """returns True if the string contains at least one exclamation point

    str -> str"""
    if x.find('!') != -1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def all_extreme(x):
    """returns true if all of the strings contain exclamation points

    str, str... -> str"""
    for word in x:
        if extreme(x) == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The problem that I am having is that I getting a AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find'. I am open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: extreme can simply be `return  x.find('!') != -1`

Comment: or `return '!' in x`. Also, your loop is only ever going to test the first item of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `extreme(word)`, not `extreme(x)`.

Also, you will encounter a problem with the `return` statements - they'll `return` after only one iteration. Save a `True` flag at the beginning of `all_extreme()`, then if one of the `word`s in `x` is not `extreme`, set the flag to `False`. Then `return` the value of the flag.

This task can also be accomplished more simply:

```
def all_extreme(x):
    return all('!' in word for word in x)
```